# CSS Flexbox Wrap. Как переносить половину элементов?

Tags: css, flexbox

Как настроить flexbox так, чтобы он переносил не один, а сразу половину элементов на новую стоку?

Comment: установить ему ширину

Comment: @Grundy т.е с помощью media установить разные значения ширины flexbox'a ?

Answer (score 0):

Разложить внутренние элементы в два контейнера со стилем:

```
flex: 0 0 50%;
```